# How to retrieve all data of a kendo ui dropdown list?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I want to pull all data of a kendo dropdown list. I create dropdown with this code:

```
$("#dropDownList").kendoDropDownList({

    dataTextField: "field",
    autoBind: true,
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            type: "POST",
            read: {
                url: "http://abc.com",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        }
    },
    select: onSelect
});
```

};

Then I tried to pull data with using

```
var data = $("#dropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList").val();
var values = [];
for (var item in data) {
    values.push(this.item);

}
```

But it didn't work. Any idea how can I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try :

```
var data = $("#dropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList");
```

Comment: It gets all drop down as an object and I used dataSource property to pull only list data, so thank you for your help.

Answer (score 10):

If you want the actual DataItems from the DDL you can get them by Viewing the DataSource:

```
$("#dropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.view()
```

You can then also find individual items easily by id if you need to:

```
$("#dropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.view().find(x=>x.Value === 'ID')
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this it will retrive all values from Kendo dropdown.

```
var values = [];
    var grid = $("#SampleDropdown").data("kendoDropDownList");

    var ds = grid.dataSource;
    var len = ds._data.length;
    if (len > 0) {
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var val = ds._data[i].Value;
            values.push(val);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you, it didn't work at first but then I remembered we explicitly bound the dataSource using 'Name' and Key'

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
 var values = [];
    var data = $("#dropDownList option").each(function(){
  values.push($(this).val());
  });
```

Comment: I tried but I dont know why "option" gives an exception here. But I solve my problem, thank you anyway.

Comment: not work using KendoComboBox, for example: var data = $("#combo option")??

Comment: @HernaldoGonzalez can you make sure  that oonly one element with id combobox exitsts in that page ? if there are multiple elements with the same id then you may not get the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#dropDownList").data('kendoDropDownList').options.optionList` - returns object with values

Answer (score 0):

**Simple one liner.**

**To get all data items:**

```
$("#myDDL").data("kendoCombo").dataSource.data();
```

**To get single property value:**

```
$("#myDDL").data("kendoCombo").dataSource.data()[0].ProductId;
```

[Reference](https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-can-i-get-the-count-of-number-of-items-in-the-combo)