# KendoComboBox MVC find value and if exist select it, if not, select other value

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-combobox

I have a KendoComboBox, in MVC mode, these Combo load ok a list of values.

Now, I need load these ComboBox but I need you to automatically preselect a certain value only if It exist in the list of values, if not find the value, preselect other value.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
    .Name("Test")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    .Placeholder("Seleccione")
    .DataTextField("name")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .Filter("contains")        
    .DataSource(source =>
    {    
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("CargaCombo", "Test");                   
        });               
    })
    .Value("TODOS")
    .Suggest(true)
)
```

I tried using Events as "Find", read using jQuery the data, but I can't.
Any Help? For Example I Tried this other post, [How to retrieve all data of a kendo ui dropdown list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250972/how-to-retrieve-all-data-of-a-kendo-ui-dropdown-list) but It not work for me, maybe as I use KendoComboBox and not KendoDropDown.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I use DataBoundEvent:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onDataBound() {        
        var user = $.trim($(".userlogged").text());    
        var encontrado = false;           
        var elementos = $("#Test").data("kendoComboBox").dataSource.data();
        $.each(elementos, function (index, value) {
            if (value.Nombre == user) {
                $("#Test").data("kendoComboBox").value(user);
                encontrado = true;
                return;
            }
        });

        if (!encontrado) {
            $("#Test").data("kendoComboBox").value(0);
        }
    }    
</script>
```

And add the Event:

```
.Events(e =>
{
    e.DataBound("onDataBound");
})
```